# Executing an Oracle procedure using PHP - possible?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, procedure

I'm trying to run a very simple Oracle procedure from PHP, using the following statement:

```
$sql = 'exec procedureName(param1, param2)';
$sql = oci_parse($connection, $sql); oci_execute($sql);
```

Running this in Oracle SQL developer returns a successful *'anonymous block completed'* message, but running this via PHP returns an *'ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement'* error.

Is there anyway to run this procedure from PHP? Many thanks

Comment: Try getting rid of "exec " in $sql.

Comment: Many thanks, good suggestion but I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking a little deeper, I think you'll need to put your procedure call inside a PL/SQL BEGIN-END pair, as in:

```
$sql = 'BEGIN procedureName(:param1, :param2); END;';
$stmt_id = oci_parse($connection, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt_id, ':param1', $value1);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt_id, ':param2', $value2);
oci_execute($stmt_id);
```

You'll need to edit the above to use whatever variable names are appropriate in the calls to `oci_bind_by_name`.

Also note that the presence of semi-colons in the SQL string is important.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'BEGIN procedureName(:param1, :param2); END;';
$stmt_id = oci_parse($connection, $sql);
oci_execute($stmt_id);
```